# Automatic compaction in CouchDB 2.2

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon, couchdb-2.0

I have read the following [article](https://smartregister.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/Documentation/pages/53805058/CouchDB+Optimization), because couchdb was busy almost all the space of my hard drive at an impressive speed.

Thanks to this article I have managed to reduce the size of my database from 19 GB to 19 MB.

But I would like the "compaction" to be done automatically, without me having to worry, so I followed the steps of that article, however, there is no way to verify that the configuration is working properly.

**How can I determine if it is working correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a CouchDB 2.2 bug. You can check it [here](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1579).

It is planned to be fixed in the next release 2.3